# How can I get the deployment name from within my container?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to set the deployment name as environment variable using the downward API but my container keeps crashing without any logging. I'm using the busybox to print the environment variables. I've had success using a Pod but no luck with a Deployment: This is my YAML:

```
--- 
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  labels: 
    app: test-d
  name: test-deploy
spec: 
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels: 
      app: test-d
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        app: test-d
    spec: 
      command: 
        - sh
        - "-c"
        - "echo Hello Kubernetes, I am $MY_DEPLOY_NAME in $MY_CLUSTER_NAME and $MY_NAMESPACE! && sleep 3600"
      containers: 
        - 
          image: busybox
          name: test-d-container
      env: 
        - 
          name: MY_DEPLOY_NAME
          valueFrom: 
            fieldRef: 
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - 
          name: MY_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom: 
            fieldRef: 
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - 
          name: MY_CLUSTER_NAME
          value: production
```

What am I missing?

**Update:**

It is clear that my indentation was messed up, thank you for pointing that out but the main part of my question is still not clear to me. How do I get the deployment name from within my container?

Comment: updated my answer with more info

Comment: @fiunchinho Ok thanks, I'll keep it open for a little bit more time to see if there maybe is someone that knows a mechanism, if not I'll accept your answer. Do you know by any chance if the generated name of a pod always have exactly two dashes with numbers as id (f.e. 'test-deploy-6bb8fb7f86-9whq4')? If so I could easily extract the deployment name from the pod name, not my preferable way but it would do the trick.

Comment: Yes, it's always the same structure. The format is `deploymentName-replicaSetName-randomAlphanumericChars`.

Comment: @fiunchinho I just encountered a pod name with only one hyphen at the end. It didn't add a second one but just extended the replica set's id with a few numbers. Why is this?

Comment: Maybe there was no Deployment object, just a ReplicaSet. And the pod was created by the ReplicaSet. You only get the deploymentName prefix is the ReplicaSet was created by a Deployment

Comment: @fiunchinho It was from a deployment object, I think it is because it was a long name 40+ characters including multiple hyphens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the wrong indentation and structure for Deployment objects.

Both the `command` key and the `env` key are part of the `container` key.

This is the right format

```
--- 
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  labels: 
    app: test-d
  name: test-deploy
spec: 
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels: 
      app: test-d
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        app: test-d
    spec: 
      containers: 
        - image: busybox
          name: test-d-container
          command: 
            - sh
            - "-c"
            - "echo Hello Kubernetes, I am $MY_DEPLOY_NAME in $MY_CLUSTER_NAME and $MY_NAMESPACE! && sleep 3600"
          env: 
            - 
              name: MY_DEPLOY_NAME
              valueFrom: 
                fieldRef: 
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - 
              name: MY_NAMESPACE
              valueFrom: 
                fieldRef: 
                  fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            - 
              name: MY_CLUSTER_NAME
              value: production
```

Remember that you can validate your Kubernetes manifests using [this online validator](https://kubeyaml.com/), or locally [using kubeval](https://github.com/instrumenta/kubeval).

Referring to the main part of the question, [you can get the object that created the Pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42274229/kubernetes-deployment-name-from-within-a-pod), but most likely that will be the ReplicaSet, not the Deployment.

The Pod name is normally generated by Kubernetes, you don't know it before hand, that's why there is a mechanism to get the name. But that is not the case for Deployments: you know the name of Deployments when creating them. I don't think there is a mechanism to get the Deployment name dynamically.

Typically, labels are used in the PodSpec of the Deployment object to add metadata.

You could also try to parse it, since the pod name (which you have) has always this format: deploymentName-replicaSetName-randomAlphanumericChars.

Comment: It deploys fine now but `MY_DEPLOY_NAME` returns the name of the Pod ('test-deploy-6bb8fb7f86-9whq4'), not the name of the Deployment. How do I get the name of the Deployment ('test-deploy')? What's wrong with `fieldPath: metadata.name`?

Comment: The Pod name is normally generated by Kubernetes, you don't know it before hand, that's why there is a mechanism to get the name. But that is not the case for Deployments: you know the name of Deployments when creating them. I don't think there is a mechanism to get the Deployment name dynamically.

Comment: @Stanko to answer your question why it is giving pod name and not deployment name. The container config you are adding in a deployment is under pod spec. Literally meaning specification for pod. So what will end up happening is the replicaset controller will take this specification and generate a pod yaml with this specification and create a pod. Now in that pod `metadata.name` will be your pod name. Hence the reason why you are getting pod name

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing any direct solution to get the deployment name from container. The workaround that I'm using is with the help of pod labels,

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app1-deployment
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app1-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: container1
          image: nginx
          env:
            - name: DEPLOYMENT_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: metadata.labels['app']


...
...
```

I'm using app as label name but deployment-name could also be better naming convention for this