# Need a deployment name passed to related pods

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-pod

I have docker image containing  a nodejs app and I deployed it via kubernetes deployment and I have 3 pods. What I need is to pass the name of the each deployment to the related pods so this way I have a unique id for each deployment which is unique to only that deployment and all pods inside that deployment can consume that id.
Also this one did not help much:

[Kubernetes deployment name from within a pod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42274229/kubernetes-deployment-name-from-within-a-pod)

I know for the fact that I can do the following in :

```
env:
  - name: unique id
    value: {{uuidv4}}
```

But I would rather the following:

```
env:
  - name: deployment name
    value: a way to get the deployment name
```

Any idea if it is even achievable?

Comment: You need to be more specific, why would you need the pod id, are you trying the pods to connect to each other to do something?

Comment: @paltaa Actually I use redis and assign one of the pods to be leader in each deployment and keep track of the leader id in redis. A new deployment leader should be assigned a new id.

Comment: @paltaa Also it is noteworthy I am not looking for pod name but deployment name since I need to see if a pods comming up are related to the old deployment or new one.

Comment: @paltaa so each deploy will create 3 pods and the code will grab the deployment pod and assign one of the pod as leader and keep track of it in redis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from the Kubernetes deployment documentation, one use case is:

> Declare the new state of the Pods by updating the PodTemplateSpec of
>   the Deployment. A new ReplicaSet is created and the Deployment manages
>   moving the Pods from the old ReplicaSet to the new one at a controlled
>   rate. Each new ReplicaSet updates the revision of the Deployment.

So knowing the deploying is not relevant unless you want to rollback. So what you need is to get the pods to see each other. In that case, you need a headless service.

https://dev.to/kaoskater08/building-a-headless-service-in-kubernetes-3bk8

There you can get the pod DNS and tag them in your Redis by IP or DNS

EDIT:

For getting the deployment, every pod has an env var called HOSTNAME, for example (in my environment):

```
HOSTNAME=stella-api-8675fcf6df-rm2m7
```

Where stella-api is the current deployment name, stella-api-8675fcf6df is the current replica set and finally, stella-api-8675fcf6df-rm2m7 would be the pod specific id

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so if I get it right there is no way to get the name of the replica set then right?

Comment: @Learner Edited got your answer

Comment: Thanks for the update which is very helpful. So for passing the HOSTNAME a an env var should I do this? {{HOSTNAME}}

Comment: HOSTNAME is an env var on every pod, if you look closely it's your pod's name, so just parse the pod name

Comment: I see your point but my issue is I do not know how to retrive it and pass it in this section: env:
  - name: pod name
    value: retrive pods name
then in my nodejs code I can use it

Comment: HOSTNAME is an environment variable of your pod, you can access it by using nodejs package dotenv

Comment: You can access your HOSTNAME of Pod using `exec` and `-- printenv` command.
`kubectl exec nginx-7bffc778db-7n77 -- printenv | grep HOSTNAME`
where nginx-7bffc778db-7n77 is a nginx light-weight pod.