# Get the Kubernetes uid of the Deployment that created the pod, from within the pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I want to be able to know the Kubernetes uid of the Deployment that created the pod, from within the pod.

The reason for this is so that the Pod can spawn another Deployment and set the `OwnerReference` of that Deployment to the original Deployment (so it gets Garbage Collected when the original Deployment is deleted).

Taking inspiration from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42274229/kubernetes-deployment-name-from-within-a-pod), I've tried*:

1. Using field refs as env vars:

```yaml
containers:
  - name: test-operator
    env:
      - name: DEPLOYMENT_UID
        valueFrom: 
          fieldRef: {fieldPath: metadata.uid}
```

2. Using `downwardAPI` and exposing through files on a volume:

```yaml
containers:
  volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/deployment-info
      name: deployment-info
volumes:
  - name: deployment-info
    downwardAPI:
      items:
      - path: "uid"
        fieldRef: {fieldPath: metadata.uid}
```

*Both of these are under `spec.template.spec` of a resource of kind: Deployment.

However for both of these the uid is that of the Pod, not the Deployment. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: what Kubernetes version you are using and where: cloud or on bare-metal?

Comment: cloud Kubernetes, version 1.20

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is correct, the `Downward API` is for `pod` rather than `deployment/replicaset`.

So I guess the solution is set the name of deployment manually in `spec.template.metadata.labels`, then adopt `Downward API` to inject the labels as env variables.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. My problem, I think, is that I want the uid of the Deployment object (for the reasons I've added in the edit above). This is a field added by Kubernetes -> https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/names/#uids. So I don't think it's possible to manually label it.

Comment: @JamesCockbain, have you found any solution for this?

Comment: @Bazhikov - I haven't found a solution myself no. I ended up setting the ownerReference of the spawned Deployment to the Pod type instead. It means that Deployment gets recreated if the Pod is deleted, but that wasn't a dealbreaker for my use-case.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible to get the UID of Deployment itself, you can set any range of `runAsUser` while creating the deployment.

Try this command to get the UIDs of the existing pods:

```
kubectl get pod -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{@.metadata.name}{" runAsUser: "}{@.spec.containers[*].securityContext.runAsUser}{" fsGroup: "}{@.spec.securityContext.fsGroup}{" seLinuxOptions: "}{@.spec.securityContext.seLinuxOptions.level}{"\n"}{end}'
```

It's not the exact what you wanted to get, but it can be a hint for you.

To set the UID while creating the `Deployment`, see the example below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: toolbox2
 labels:
   app: toolbox2
spec:
 replicas: 3
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: toolbox2
 template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       app: toolbox2
   spec:
     securityContext:
       supplementalGroups: [1000620001]
       seLinuxOptions:
           level: s0:c25,c10
     containers:
     - name: net-toolbox
       image: quay.io/wcaban/net-toolbox
       ports:
       - containerPort: 2000
       securityContext:
           runAsUser: 1000620001
```